# IBM DB2 - ODBC Issue

Tags: sql, db2

I have installed "IBM Data Studio" stand alone application V3.1 to access DB2.

And, now I'm trying to establish DB connection using QTP scripts. But couldn't make due to some connectivity issue. I've got some connectivity code from other threads and have it ready, but suspecting that my machine has ODBC driver issue.

So I'm just looking to know whether my machine has proper ODBC driver installed to establish this connectivity or not. So can anyone suggest some checkpoints for this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Yup,,, I have spotted the issue,,,,! :)

Please refer to the blog http://merisocch.blogspot.in/ for detailed information on DB2 connection establishment...!